# How does a SMS provider like twilio work?

Tags: sms

Simple question, I'm asking here as I don't exactly know how to phrase this question correctly, I'm interested in knowing how SMS providers work, e.g how do they send you that message? who does it go through? how would you send an SMS without a middle man like twilio (without using a sim card)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the same as twilio, and get a contract with the phone companies to feed things directly into their network.